# How to reuse an LDAP connection in Unboundid LDAP SDK?

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have tried to reuse an LDAP connection in Unboundid LDAP SDK using the following code:

```
if  (ldapConnection.isConnected()) {
    //Connection is still connected.
} else {
    try {
        // Connection is not connected. Try to reconnect
        ldapConnection.reconnect();
    } catch (LDAPException e) {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `ldapConnection.isConnected()` returns true and I get exception later in my code.

What I do wrong?
How to reuse an LDAP connection in Unboundid LDAP SDK?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you are trying to accomplish and why you are using the ldapConnection.reconnect() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are using the ldapConnection.reconnect() method vs simply using BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);

You might also consider using "a connection pool, even if that pool only has a single connection.  Connection pools have excellent support for connection management and dealing with connections that have become invalid, and they also offer much better options for failover in that they can be configured with information about multiple servers (through the ServerSet API) so that the best server can be selected." (From http://sourceforge.net/p/ldap-sdk/discussion/1001257/thread/2cd4e0de/#14b5

-jim

Comment: Thanks, I will use the connection pool